# How can I go to particular line in Vim?

Tags: vim

I have typed `gg` to go to the beginning of the file in Vim. Now how can I directly go to a particular line such as `505`?

Comment: Download [this](http://www.viemu.com/vi-vim-cheat-sheet-svg.zip), print it and post it somewhere.

Comment: In addition to all the fine answers below, may I suggest reading `:help motion`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can either do:

```
:<linenum>
```

or

```
<linenum>gg
```

in normal mode.

Also, `G`, always in normal mode, gets you to the end of the file.

Comment: how would i enter command mode ? What is the basic difference between the two options that you mentioned ?

Comment: Well, you are in command mode by default when you edit a file.

Comment: is Insert mode==command mode ?

Comment: No it isn't. In insertion mode, you enter text freely (by default, vim will display `-- INSERT --` or `-- REPLACE --` at the bottom of the window when you are in insert mode) and press Esc to get back to command mode.

Comment: so that means command mode==normal mode right ?

Comment: That would be a way to put it, yes.

Comment: @fge There already is fixed terminology. `:` enters *command* mode. Default mode where `gg` works is *normal*. `gg` itself is *command*. Or *normal-mode command* as *command* may as well refer to `:e`, and this is what it refers to by default. Don’t ever refer to *normal* mode as to *command*, this just leads to misunderstanding between those who know vim terminology and those who don’t.

Comment: I replaced *command* with *normal* in your post. By the way, `<number>G` has exactly the same meaning as `<number>gg`.

Answer (score 1):

just :505

and it jumps to line 505

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative:

```
505G
```

that works, too.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `:505` (or)
`vim file +505` command
To open file and go to line 505